# Ubuntu goes black after upgrading (using VirtualBox)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, virtualbox, reboot

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 within Oracle VirtualBox 4.3. I saw a notification to upgrade some package which I couldn't remember, to be honest. After upgrading process, I was asked to reboot, then everything went black. I tried recovery mode, but nothing changed. I googled some solutions on ask Ubuntu too, but couldn't fix it.

This is the log file

```
VirtualBox COM Server 4.3.18 r96516 win.amd64 (Oct 11 2014 13:21:57) release log
00:00:00.000000 main     Log opened 2015-01-05T09:45:59.379303100Z
00:00:00.000000 main     Build Type: release
00:00:00.000000 main     OS Product: Windows 7
00:00:00.000000 main     OS Release: 6.1.7601
00:00:00.000000 main     OS Service Pack: 1
00:00:00.015600 main     DMI Product Name: Precision T5610
00:00:00.031200 main     DMI Product Version: 01
00:00:00.031200 main     Host RAM: 65480MB total, 59563MB available
00:00:00.031200 main     Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe
00:00:00.031200 main     Process ID: 7252
00:00:00.031200 main     Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.031200          Loading settings file "C:\Users\tranq/.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.12-windows"
00:00:00.187200          HostDnsMonitorProxy: Host's DNS information updated:
00:00:00.187200          DNS server 1: 10.146.243.101
00:00:00.187200          DNS server 2: 10.146.243.100
00:00:00.187200          DNS server 3: 10.35.220.37
00:00:00.187200          DNS domain: ads.autodesk.com
00:00:00.218400          VDInit finished
00:00:00.218400          Loading settings file "C:\Users\tranq\VirtualBox VMs\InfraWorks\InfraWorks.vbox" with version "1.14-windows"
00:00:00.218400          Loading settings file "C:\Users\tranq\VirtualBox VMs\Jenkins\Jenkins.vbox" with version "1.14-windows"
00:00:06.783848          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048} aComponent={Machine} aText={Machine is not locked for session (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false
00:00:09.576477          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={3295e6ce-b051-47b2-9514-2c588bfe7554} aComponent={ExtPackManager} aText={No extension pack by the name 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' was found}, preserve=false
00:00:09.585979          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={Saved screenshot data is not available (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false
00:11:41.046159          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048} aComponent={Machine} aText={Machine is not locked for session (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false
00:11:43.174842          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={3295e6ce-b051-47b2-9514-2c588bfe7554} aComponent={ExtPackManager} aText={No extension pack by the name 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' was found}, preserve=false
00:11:43.183843          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={Saved screenshot data is not available (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false
00:32:48.585572          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048} aComponent={Machine} aText={Machine is not locked for session (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false
00:32:50.734157          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={3295e6ce-b051-47b2-9514-2c588bfe7554} aComponent={ExtPackManager} aText={No extension pack by the name 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' was found}, preserve=false
```

Any thoughts appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It's Nvidia driver update. just uninstalled them.